# net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR from EC2 instance on AWS, can't get use of SSL certificate bc domain belongs to amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

So I'm using an EC2 instance for a backend that creates a checkout session for my website. The website runs on S3. My problem is that when I click on checkout, it gives this error in the console: POST https://ec2-3-73-74-49.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/create-checkout-session net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. If I open up this URL with http it shows me a "Hello World", like it should, but if I open it with https, it times out. I searched a lot for it but in the internet there's just that you have to have a SSL certificate, and I can't have a SSL certificate because this domain belongs to amazon. How can I fix this?

My index.js file that starts with the command "npm start" looks like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });
const createCheckoutSession = require('./api//checkout');
const webhook = require('./api/webhook');

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.use(express.json({
    verify: (req, res, buffer) => req['rawBody'] = buffer,
}));

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World'));

app.post('/create-checkout-session', createCheckoutSession);

app.post('/webhook', webhook);

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server listening on port', port));
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your website is being service by SSL on a domain you own already. You just need to point a subdomain of that domain to your EC2 instance, then you can create an SSL certificate for that subdomain.